# How can i define hook on Specified controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

Here, I'm trying to define hooks on only one Controller. how can i set them up?

I've Define hooks as `$hook['pre_controller']=arra('....')`. but it showing on all Controller and  i want to define hook on just Home Controller. suggest me please.

Comment: update question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example your controller name is `YourController`, the first step is to define your hook under `hooks.php` file,

```
// hooks.php
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'MyHook',
    'function' => 'HookMethod',
    'filename' => 'MyHook.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array()
);
```

Define your `MyHook.php` as below under `hooks` folder.

```
<?php
// MyHook.php    
class MyHook
{
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }    

    public function HookMethod()
    {
        // check here loaded controller is desired one
        if (is_subclass_of($this->CI, 'YourController')) {
           // write your desired code here.
        }
    }    
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but this will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

> you may try this. it's working fine

**config/hooks.php**

```
$hook['test'] = array(   
     'class' => 'Exm',   
     'function' => 'tut',   
     'filename' => 'exm.php',   
     'filepath' => 'hooks',   
);
```

**application/hooks/exm.php**

```
class Exm extends CI_Hooks {   
    public function tut()   
    {   
     echo "Welcome to Hooks File";   
    }
}
```

**application/controller/example.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');   

class Example extends CI_Controller {   
public function index()   
  {   
    echo "Hooks Example";   
    $this->hooks->call_hook('test');
  }   
}
```